# PostgresSQL is not working It is showing errors

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

When I try to load Postgres SQL on cmd by running psql postgres postgres it is saying.

psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

what should I do When I try to connect using pgadmin4 and creating a new server when I use the port has 5432 it is showing errors when I try 5433 it is saying Connection Timed Out

Comment: Did you start the PostgreSQL server? Could you show the log lines from the server that says that the server has started? And how did you start the server?

Comment: I didn't start any server can you tell me how to do it

Comment: Did you (or somebody else) install PostgreSQL? Without starting it, it can't work

Comment: I am the one installed it but when it reaches the end of the installation it shows sql modules cannot be loaded to server

Comment: The server is visible in windows services but when I try to start it it is showing an error